# Is possible to bind to express callback promise?

Tags: node.js, express, promise

Is possible to bind to express callback promise ?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.param('test', some_function);
```

and I already have function which has functionality of som_function but it returns promise.
How to bind promise to url ?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to wrap it with a function that has the signature required by Express.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.param('test', function (req, res, next, id) {
    some_function().done(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(500); // boo
            return;
        }
        next(); // yay
    });
});
```